# angular custom charting svg or canvas or d3 or html?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

i am looking for some library/framework/or even build from scratch that gets binds with the model and provides 2 way binding? Is SVG or Canvas is the best option. looks like SVG to me.

Was looking at D23.js and angular integration. But does it allow to create custom chart or should i go ahead building from scratch without using any library/framework.

So if it is svg, then on clicking or dragging an svg element should be able to call a function in angular scope.

Please give pointers on where to start.

Comment: D3js has no prepared charts, but is a framework for charts. It just has lots of examples for many kinds of charts.

Comment: can i create my kind of chart with d3

Comment: Probably yes. Take one of the example as a basis and modify it until you got your chart.

Comment: Looks Good .. Will i still have dependency on D3. what about integrating D3 in angular? Directives? ? Whats the best way.

Comment: You will have the dependency. I do not know about angular, so can't help you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use Highcharts. Also you can find angular module for highcharts.